# Swift Parse schema mismatch expected Pointer but got [object Object]

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and got this error.

[Error]: schema mismatch for Like.toPost; expected Pointer but got [object Object] (Code: 111, Version: 1.13.0).

I've googled quite a bit to no avail so here is my code.

```
// Inside ParseHelper class
static func likePost(user: PFUser, post: Post) {
    let likedObject = PFObject(className: ParseLikeClass)
    likedObject[ParseLikeFromUser] = user
    likedObject[ParseLikeToPost] = post

    likedObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
}
// Inside viewController
private var dataSource = [Post]()

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt,   inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
    let post = dataSource[Int(index)]
    if direction == SwipeResultDirection.Right {

        ParseHelper.likePost(PFUser.currentUser()!, post: post)
    }
}
```

I have a Post class and a Like class (with two added columns fromUser and toPost) set up in the Parse server. I'm using the Koloda pod and when I swipe right I get the error. How can I pass a pointer and not the object itself?